# vue 3 + vuex cart Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'qty')(product quantity in the cart needed to be updated)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

so I get the error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'qty')" because I try to add the same product in the cart so it's quantity(and price) will update in the cart.

- when I do it from shop.vue it works and update the total price, but in the cart the same button does not work and showing me the error above.

how can I make it work? what is missing? thanks.

the code:

shop.vue

```
<template>
    Cart Items: <cart-badge :count="cartLength">{{ count }}</cart-badge>
    <div class="shop">
        <div class="products" v-for="Product in products" :key="Product.id">
            <h1>{{ Product.name }}</h1> <img :src="Product.pic" width="400" /> <br>
            {{ Product.description }} <br>
            {{ "$" + Product.price }} <br>
            <button class="addToCart" @click="addToCart(Product)">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CartBadge from '../components/CartBadge.vue';
import { mapMutations, mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: 'shop',
    methods: {
        ...mapMutations([
            'addToCart',
        ])
    },
    components: {
        'cart-badge': CartBadge
    },
    computed: {
        cartLength() {
            return this.$store.state.cart.length;
        },
        products() {
            return this.$store.state.Product;
        },
        ...mapState([
            "cart"
        ]),
    },
}
</script>
```

db.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "iphone 11",
    "pic": "/pics/iphone11.jpg",
    "description": "newest iphone!",
    "price": 999,
    "qty": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "galaxy s22",
    "pic": "/pics/galaxy22.jpg",
    "description": "a new phone from samsung!",
    "price": 1200,
    "qty": 10
  }
]
```

store.js

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import Product from "../db.json";

export default createStore({
  state: {
    cart: [],
    Product,
  },
  getters: {
    cart: (state) => state.cart,
    cartSum: (state) => {
      return state.cart.reduce((total, Product) => {
        return (total += Product.price * Product.qty);
      }, 0);
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    addToCart: (state, item) => {
      let product = state.Product.find((product) => product.id === item.id);

      let cartProduct = state.cart.find((product) => product.id === item.id);

      if (cartProduct) {
        cartProduct.qty++;
      } else {
        state.cart.push({
          ...product,
          stock: product.qty,
          qty: 1,
        });
      }
      product.qty--;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    addToCart(context, payload) {
      context.commit("addToCart", payload);
    },
  },
  modules: {},
});
```

cart.vue

```
<template>
    <h1>Cart</h1>
    <div class="cartItems">
        Cart Items: <cart-badge :count="cartLength">{{ count }}</cart-badge>
        <p v-if="!cart.length">Your cart is empty! please add something to the cart</p>
        <div class="products" v-for="Product in cart" :key="Product.id">name: {{ Product.name }} price: {{ Product.price
        }}</div>
        <button v-if="cart.length" class="removeFromCart" @click="removeFromCart(Product)">X</button>
        <button v-if="cart.length" class="increment" @click="addToCart()">+</button>
        <button v-if="cart.length" class="decrement" @click="removeFromCart()">-</button>
        <strong v-if="cart.length">Total ${{ cartSum }}</strong>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CartBadge from '../components/CartBadge.vue';
import { mapGetters, mapState } from 'vuex';
import Product from "../db.json"

export default {
    name: 'Cart',
    components: {
        'cart-badge': CartBadge
    },
    computed: {
        cartLength() {
            return this.$store.state.cart.length;
        },
        products() {
            return this.$store.state.Product;
        },
        ...mapGetters([
            "cartSum"
        ]),
        ...mapState([
            "cart"
        ]),
    },
    methods: {
        removeFromCart(Product) {
            this.$store.state.cart.splice(Product)
            console.log(this.$store.state.cart)
        },
        addToCart() {
            this.$store.dispatch("addToCart", this.products);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

update: I have tried this: `addToCart(product) { this.$store.dispatch("addToCart", product); }`

but now I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In shop.vue you call addToCart mutation with only one product (@click="addToCart(Product)") but in cart.vue you call addToCart with an array of product (this.$store.dispatch("addToCart", this.products))

Comment: so what should I use? and how?

Comment: i tried both and nothing is working...

Comment: you sould provide the product which you want to increment de quantity to your addToCart method :

Comment: addToCart(product) {
            this.$store.dispatch("addToCart", product);
}

Comment: it is not working. i'm getting this error now: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')